AppxManifest.xml : error APPX0501: Validation error. error C00CE012: App manifest validation error:
All of sudden started getting this error message for builds. Application is UWP VS 2017.
AppxManifest.xml : error APPX0501: Validation error. error C00CE012: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 64, Column 8, Reason: Content for element {http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}InProcessServer' is incomplete according to the DTD/Schema. Expecting: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}ActivatableClass.
I see that the \bin\x64\Release\AppxManifest.xml file have below lines added
 <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>CLRHost.dll</Path>
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>



 <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>MyCompany.MyApp.UWP.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="MyCompany.MyApp.UWP.BackgroundTasks.PreInstallTask" ThreadingModel="MTA" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="MyCompany.MyApp.UWP.BackgroundTasks.NotificationManager" ThreadingModel="MTA" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="MyCompany.MyApp.UWP.BackgroundTasks.ToastResponseHandler" ThreadingModel="MTA" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>


According to the error message, it may be a problem with InProcessServer. You can refer to the documentation first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-inprocessserver

first block is outside of Extensions block. That is not correct.
The file is being created by build process, so you might want to look at the manifest file within your project. Sometimes rebuilding the project folder is helpful too.
